# Show Category images in an over-ridden module template

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I'm trying to over-ride the default layout template of Categories list within the Module

> mod_articles_categories

The reason for that is to be able to display the images associated with each category which is set in the params of each category.

The code that I found to show those images is

> json_decode($item->params)->image

But it's not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" way would be to use something like this within the `foreach ($list as $item) :`

```
<?php
$params = new JRegistry();
$params->loadString($item->params);
$image = $params->get('image');
if ($image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

But you code should work as well. At least it does when I tested it locally. The code I posted would allow you to set a default value for the param. Like `$params->get('image', 'foo/bar.png');`. Other than that it does about the same.